# Clicking on buttom using httprequest in VBS

Tags: vba, xmlhttprequest

I want to simulate `ie.document.getElementbyId("buttom_id").(0).click` in `XMLHTTPREQUEST`.

Therefore in clicking the button:

1. Right click on the webpage and select 'INSPECT'
2. Select network tab
3. Copy all as HAR

This interaction is below:
[HAR FILE](http://textuploader.com/dr1bt)

My code is below:

```
Function SaveGraphImageFromURLs( fileUrl, filePath)

Dim FileNum As Long
Dim FileData() As Byte
Dim WHTTP As Object

fileUrl = "http://80.191.214.122/Orion/Charts/CustomChartData.ashx?Calculate95thPercentile=True&CalculateTrendLine=True&ChartDateSpan=1&ChartInitialZoom=yesterday&ChartName=MMAvgBps&ChartSubTitle=%24%7bZoomRange%7d&ChartTitle=%24%7bCaption%7d&Height=0&NetObject=I%3a21067&ResourceID=69&SampleSize=30&Width=640&DataFormat=ChartData&NetObjectIds=21067"

WHTTP.Open "post", fileUrl, False
WHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
WHTTP.send

FileData = WHTTP.responseBody
Set WHTTP = Nothing

'Save the file
FileNum = FreeFile

Open filePath For Binary Access Write As #FileNum
Put #FileNum, 1, FileData
Close #FileNum
Debug.Print "File has been saved!", vbInformation, "Success"
End Function
```

Comment: The code you posted is not VBScript. Also, what is your question? Does something not work?

Comment: Can't open the provided URL since I have no credentials. What finally do you want to achieve by clicking the button? Please add the expected output to the question. The only relevant data I can see within your HAR is an HTML webpage in 2nd response containing a table, see the [screenshot by the link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C8Y8F.png).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i could resolve problem :)
by replacing

```
    Function SaveGraphImageFromURLs( fileUrl, filePath)

Dim FileNum As Long
Dim FileData() As Byte
Dim WHTTP As Object

fileUrl = "http://80.191.214.122/Orion/Charts/CustomChartData.ashx?Calculate95thPercentile=True&CalculateTrendLine=True&ChartDateSpan=1&ChartInitialZoom=yesterday&ChartName=MMAvgBps&ChartSubTitle=%24%7bZoomRange%7d&ChartTitle=%24%7bCaption%7d&Height=0&NetObject=I%3a21067&ResourceID=69&SampleSize=30&Width=640&DataFormat=ChartData&NetObjectIds=21067"

displaydata = "DisplayDetails=eyJkYXRhVXJsIjoiL09yaW9uL0ludGVyZmFjZXMvU2VydmljZXMvSW50ZXJmYWNlQ2hhcnREYXRhLmFzbXgvTU1BdmdCcHMiLCJ0aXRsZSI6IkZhc3RFdGhlcm5ldDEvMC80OCA%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"
displaydata = displaydata & "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%3D%3D"

WHTTP.Open "post", fileUrl, False
WHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
WHTTP.send displaydata

FileData = WHTTP.responseBody
Set WHTTP = Nothing

'Save the file
FileNum = FreeFile

Open filePath For Binary Access Write As #FileNum
Put #FileNum, 1, FileData
Close #FileNum
Debug.Print "File has been saved!", vbInformation, "Success"
End Function
```